# NodeJS: Session store for Monk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, monk

I'm trying out MeanJS, which uses Mongoose on top of MongoDB. Given my project needs, I would rather use Monk. I'm having trouble figuring out the magic behind session stores.

```
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
var db = mongoose.connect("localhost:...", function(err){});

app.use(session({
    secret: 'foo',
    store: new MongoStore({db: db.connection.db})
}));
```

How do I store a session in my app using Monk, that would allow other modules to access it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Monk for your other mongoDB behavior and still use connect-mongo to store sessions.

In Express 3.x (which it seems you're using based on your code):

```
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express),

app.use(session({
    secret: 'foo',
    store: new MongoStore({url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'})
}));
```

In this case, Monk isn't actually being used as MongoStore is creating a new connection to the db using the [native driver's connection string](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/).  I tested this without requiring the official mongo driver or Monk.

You just need to have a mongod instance running (in this case at the default port 27017).

You can reference this method in the [connect-mongo readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo#create-a-new-connection-from-a-mongodb-connection-string)

For Express 4.x (which I use), the code is similar but you must install and require the `express-session` module separately as it's no longer packaged with express. Also there are two options that the newest version of express-session requires to be explicit as shown below.

```
var session = require('express-session'),
    MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'foo',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    store: new MongoStore({url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'})
}));
```